# Apache chemistry internal server error on setContentStream

Tags: java, alfresco, apache-chemistry

I'm trying to replace a document on alfresco with Apache chemistry.
I create an inputstream from a file stored on disk, i create a contenstream with the constructor ContentStreamImpl and i try to replace the document with the .setContentStream method.
The result of this operation is

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Internal Server Error
```

This is the part of my code:

```
        InputStream newDoc = new FileInputStream(global.getPathTemp() + filename);
        ContentStream content = new ContentStreamImpl("Prova", BigInteger.valueOf(newDoc.available()), mimetype, newDoc);

        alfDoc.setContentStream(content, true);
```

Can someone help me??

Comment: is there any chance you can post the Alfresco server logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with

```
  alfDoc.setContentStream(content, true, true);
```